# Developing a software framework - how to test it?

Tags: java, testing

I'm developing a framework for simplifying the development of client-server applications for a school project. I will be developing it using Java.

The scope of the project is rather large, but in short:

- The server must manage multiple clients and be able to verify their integrity
- The server must provide a way to develop tasks in pure Java code and register them
- The client must be able to request tasks (without knowledge of their code implementation)
- There must be a way to transfer data generically between sockets (i.e. any data type)

... And many more sub-points.

I'm a bit stuck on how to properly test the framework once I begin developing it.

I was thinking about asking some of my peers to implement some simple test cases, using framework documentation as guideline, but how do I properly document this?

How can I smartly test the performance? Naturally, I want the framework to perform as good as it can. I am thinking about profiling it and see if I can get some useful data from that.

Is it possible to quantify how much time is saved using a framework rather than building that functionality in addition to the application's functionality?

Something I'm not even thinking about?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire Testing approach will be too big for a singe answer. Since your question is quite broad, maybe it's better to split it in couple of smaller and more concrete questions, also provide design or code samples.

As beginning - you already have your topics, about the

> scope of the project

so you can consider the four basic and more frequently used [Testing levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing#Testing_levels) : unit testing, integration, system, and acceptance testing. Also applicable is the same for the [Testing types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing#Testing_Types) - Regression, Functional and non-functional (Usability, Security) testing.

Since you'll be the main person responsible for the development I can advice you to take a look at the [Test driven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) approach. This will also help with

> about asking some of my peers to implement some simple test cases

In current situation the

> smartly test the performance

will be mostly related to the the communications and web-services, since it's nature is a lot more likely to produce such problems, than the code itself. So

> thinking about profiling it

is a good idea, but deal with bottlenecks will not be enough.